# what is the parameter database.batchablecontext?

Tags: apex, batch, asyncapexjob

I was learning batch apex and it has three method which is start,execute and finish. Each method has a parameter `Database.BatchableContext`.

What is this parameter and why it is being used in all three methods?

Comment: did you look in [the doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchablecontext.htm?search_text=batchableContext) ?  Please elaborate using [edit] after reading the doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common use case for this is in the `finish()` method to see if any of the `execute` transactions had errors

```
public void finish(BatchableContext bc) {

  AsyncApexJob[] jobs = [SELECT Id, NumberOfErrors 
    FROM AsyncApexJob 
    WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];

  if (jobs[0].NumberOfErrors > 0) {..do something, perhaps log/message}
}
```

For `start()`, you might want to abort the job if you detect another batchable already running.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I've never used that parameter. But it is described in [BatchableContext Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchablecontext.htm) as:

> BatchableContext Interface
> Represents the parameter type of a batch
>   job method and contains the batch job ID.

Useful I guess if you want to manipulate the job that runs the batchable e.g. to abort it via `System.abortJob`.